# decode textarea to send in an email

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email

i'm having trouble sending the value of a textarea in a form. I've done some research and found that i need to decode it before sending. i don't know if i need to do this in the html or in the php send mail script or wether i need something in both.

this is the code i have for sanitizing the textarea in the PHP send mail script...

```
$coverletter = filter_var($_POST["coverletter"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

this is my html...

```
<textarea id="coverletter" class="required"></textarea>
```

Comment: give name attribute to textarea

Comment: PHP will decode it when populating `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `textarea` element need a `name` attribute

```
<textarea id="coverletter" name="coverletter" class="required"></textarea>
```